# Regex to exclude only numbers

Tags: python, pandas, regex, filter

I have this table

| Stars |
| --- |
| 3 stars |
| Stars 20 |
| 901stars |
| 8 |

I'm using python to filter the table but I'm not sure of the regex to reject 8. `[^0-9]` will flag `3 stars, 901stars` as errors too but I just want to flag that 8 is incorrect based on the regex.

The regex I need would only flag out the numbers (not number+string or string+number).

Comment: Would `8` be a string `'8'` or a number `8`?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov a number

Comment: If `8` is a number (that is, a Python integer), you need to check for the type of the table elements, not use a regex. Or turn all elements into a string first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest  `\d+$` to match 1 or more digits at the end of the line. (or even `^\d+$` to search from beginning of line).

disclaimer: I don't have a clue wrt Python, but if has a standard rx library, this should work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way without using regex.

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Stars'],errors = 'coerce').isna()
```